# Re-developing an app from scratch?

Tags: android, google-play

This is not a programming question but I feel SO is the right place to put it in.

There is an android app in the market. Our job is to upgrade the app in a huge way. There is so much to change to the point where we decided to start a new project from scratch.

My question is: **in order to be able to replace (upgrade) the existing app in the Play store**, What should we do? Keep the same package name? or the sign key is enough? or both? or what?

Thanks for your help and sorry if this is not the right place.

Comment: Here is the Android Developers blog on this exact issue: [Things That Cannot Change](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/06/things-that-cannot-change.html)

Comment: I see you have your answer but there's something I'd like to point out. Are you sure you'd want to start the project from scratch? If it's a small app it might be a good idea. But if it's something huge I would suggest doing some refractoring and reorganizing to the existing code and making the necessary modifications. Because you run the risk of re-generating old bugs that may have been previously fixed, especially if the original author(s) aren't available anymore.

Comment: I'm wondering the same thing for iPhone - asked it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13089945/rebuilding-an-iphone-app-from-scratch

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You must have both the same package name and the same signature key. Also, if it has any sort of intents/actions that can be launched from other applications, you may want to keep those the same (in case a user has setup a shortcut to them).

**Package name** is how the Play Store determines one app from another. They have to be unique for each app. You can't change it after you've uploaded the original if you're wanting to upgrade the existing app.

**The signing key** is how the Play Store verifies that you are the original developer. If you ever lose or change this key **you will absolutely not be able to update the original application!**

Answer (score 4):

> **in order to be able to replace (upgrade) the existing app in the Play store,** What should we do?

You need both **"same package name and the same signing key"**

Or if you want to change any of this, You always have option to unpublish your application from Play store.(From developer console you can unpublish it)

and then u can upload a new app.