# Rebuilding an iPhone app from scratch?

Tags: iphone, ios

I have the [same question as this guy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11367507/re-developing-an-app-from-scratch), but for iPhone instead of Android. we're rebuilding a previously developed iPhone app entirely from scratch (new dev shop too), what would be required to treat its publishing as an *update* instead of a new app? Is package name & signing key sufficient?

(note I'm creating a new question because that whole discussion ended up being Android-specific)

Comment: Pretty much just the bundle identifier. Provisioning profiles will all fall into place automatically if the bundle id matches.

Comment: No, no, no!!!  You don't understand!!  No programmer since Ada, Lady Lovelace has ever built an application from scratch -- you always copy from something else.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to treat it as an update if you are on the same developer who submitted it. If you do not have access to the account that submitted it, you will need to submit it anew. It could get tricky if you have a different Apple login account to iTunes Connect than the original submitter.